# Make jquery validation check for new form elements, or manually add them

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin to validate a form. when one thing is selected in a selectbox a new selectbox is added trough ajax. this new element has class required but when I try to submit, it is not validated.

I know this is because when the validation plugin is initialized on the form the classes are checked to see which validations will be necessary. When a new item is added it is not checked for any classes, or initialized at all for that matter.

Is there a way to add the selectbox to the validation after it is initialized, maybe reinit the validation making it use its previous settings but rechecking its elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with a fresh look, i found out that my selectboxes all had the name of `undefined`  because of a mis-capitalized varname. This means only the first selectbox got validated. `$field.rules('add', {required: true });` was not necessary because the class required did take this time.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options here. In jquery.validate.js there is a `rules` plugin. You can use it like so:

```
$field.rules('add', {required: true }); // additional rules
```

The plugin uses the fields' form to figure out what validator should be associated with the field. Documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules)

If you want the validation rules to come from the data annotations it is a little more complicated. Let me know what you are going for.